# p-adic Hecke Operators

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, hecke-algebras

## p-adic Hecke Operators in the Iwahori-Hecke Algebra $C_c(J\backslash G(F)/J)$

Let $F$ be a non-archimedean local field, $\mathcal{O}$ its ring of integers, $\mathfrak{p}$ its maximal ideal and $\pi$ a uniformizer. I shall use $\kappa(F)$ to denote the residue field of $F$.

Let further $G = GL_n$ denote the standard algebraic group scheme of the general linear group. Further I shall denote by

- $T$ : The standard split torus of $G$ consisting of diagonal matrices,
- $B$ : the standard Borel subgroup of $G$ of upper-triangular matrices with non-zero elements on the diagonal,
- $U$ : the standard unipotent subgroup of $G$ of upper-triangular matrices with $1$'s on the diagonal principal. Hence $B = TU$. I will also use $U^{-}$ for the subgroup of lower-diagonal matrices with $1$'s on its diagonal principal.

The roots and the Bruhat order are chosen in a standard way, i.e. all roots $\alpha_{ij}$ shall be positive iff $i > j$ and negative otherwise. For my needs, I realize the Weyl-Group $W = W(G(F),T(F))$ inside $G(\mathcal{O})$ by dropping the modulo $T(\mathcal{O})$-condition (this won't have any effect in my setting).

The **Iwahori subgroup** J of $G(F)$ is defined as the preimage of $B(\kappa(F))$ under the canonical projection $G(\mathcal{O}) \to G(\kappa(F))$. In other words
$$
J = \begin{pmatrix}
  \mathcal{O}^{\times} & \mathcal{O} & \ldots & \mathcal{O} \\
  \mathfrak{p} & \mathcal{O}^{\times} & \ddots & \vdots \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \mathcal{O} \\
  \mathfrak{p} & \ldots & \mathfrak{p} & \mathcal{O}^{\times}
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
The Iwahori subgroup may be decomposed as the direct product
$$
J = U^{-}(\mathfrak{p})T(\mathcal{O})U(\mathcal{O}).
$$
The **(Iwahori-)Hecke-Algebra** $\mathcal{H}$ is the space of $\mathbb{C}$-valued functions on $G(F)$, that are

1. *Iwahori-bi-invariant*, i.e. $f(jgj') = f(g)$ for $j,j' \in J$ and $g \in G(F)$.
2. compactly supported
3. smooth, i.e. locally constant.

It is a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra under the convolution product given by
$$
(f \ast g)(x) = \int_{G(F)} f(xy^{-1})g(y)dy,
$$
where the Haar measure on $G(F)$ is chosen such that $vol(J,dg)=1$.

It is known, that as complex vector spaces,
$$
\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}_W \otimes X_{*}(T(F)),
$$
where $\mathcal{H}_W$ is the Hecke-algebra of $W$ (not necessary here) and $X_{*}(T(F))$ is the (commutative) group of rational cocharacters of $F$ (these are rational homs $F^{\times} \to T(F)/T(\mathcal{O})$. The cocharacter group $X_{*}(T(F))$ is known to be a free abelian group of rank n, and since I can drop the 'modulo $T(\mathcal{O})$'-condition, I will simply write
$$
\pi^{\lambda} = \begin{pmatrix}
  \pi^{\lambda_1} & &  \\
& \ddots & \\
  & & \pi^{\lambda_n}
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
for the image of $\pi$ under some $\lambda \in X_{*}(T(F))$.

The group of cocharacters can be realized inside $\mathcal{H}$ as follows: for a dominant $\lambda\in X_{*}(T(F))$ one defines the Hecke-Operator
$$
T_{\lambda} := ch(J\pi^{\lambda}J),
$$
where by $ch(\cdot)$ I mean the characteristic function of $\cdot$. As far as I understand it, if $\lambda\in X_{*}(T(F))$ is *any*(!) cocharacter, there are dominant $\lambda', \lambda'' \in  X_{*}(T(F))$ s.t. $\lambda = \lambda' - \lambda''$ and one defines
$$
T_{\lambda} := T_{\lambda'} T^{-1}_{\lambda''}. 
$$
The definition should be independent on the choice of $\lambda'$ and $\lambda''$.

**Question:** I was wondering if there is any nice description of these $T^{-1}_{\lambda''}$, maybe any reference?

**Example:** I computed it in the simplest case when $F = \mathbb{Q}_p$, $G = GL_2$ and $\lambda = (1,0)$, (the unifromizer is $\pi = p$) and I got something like
$$
T^{-1}_{(1,0)} = \frac{1}{p} ch(Jp^{-(1,0)}J) - \frac{1}{p(p-1)} ch(J \begin{pmatrix}
  1 &  \\
1 & 1
 \end{pmatrix} J).
$$

Comment: I suggest that you will get a better response on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/).

Comment: Thank you for your swift answer Somos! I will post it there too.